Runtime ABI-encoded contract method
I am building an application that gets tokens at runtime, I need to transfer some of them and I am attempting to calculate the required gas.
Below is a example of the gas calculation code, but it requires the contract ABI for the Data object in the CallMsg.
package main

    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "math/big"

        "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
        "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
        "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    )

    func main() {
        // Connect to the Ethereum client
        client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_API_KEY")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to the Ethereum client: %v", err)
        }

        // Create context
        ctx := context.Background()

        // Suggest a gas tip cap (miner's tip)
        tip, err := client.SuggestGasTipCap(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to suggest gas tip cap: %v", err)
        }

        // Fetch the base fee for the next block
        header, err := client.HeaderByNumber(ctx, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to get header: %v", err)
        }

        // Specify the sender, can be any valid Ethereum address
        fromAddress := common.HexToAddress("0xYourAddressHere")

        // Specify the recipient, can be any valid Ethereum address
        toAddress := common.HexToAddress("0xRecipientAddressHere")

        // Prepare call message for gas estimation
        callMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{
            From:     fromAddress,
            To:       &toAddress,
            GasFeeCap: new(big.Int).Add(header.BaseFee, tip),
            GasTipCap: tip,
            Value:    big.NewInt(0),
            Data:     nil, //<--input data, usually an ABI-encoded contract method invocation
        }

        // Estimate the gas required for the transaction
        gasLimit, err := client.EstimateGas(ctx, callMsg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to estimate gas needed: %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Estimated Gas: %v\n", gasLimit)
    }

How can I get the ABI at runtime or is there a different a different solution?

To get the ABI-encoded contract method
invocation, you can use a library like go-ethereum/accounts/abi, which provides utilities to encode and decode ABI data.
Here's the minimal implementation:
import (
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
)

// Replace these values with your actual contract ABI and method name
abiJSON := `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setValue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]`
methodName := "setValue"

// Parse the ABI
contractABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(abiJSON))
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Get the method signature
method, err := contractABI.Methods[methodName].Inputs.Pack(arg1)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Set the Data field in your call message
callMsg.Data = method

Replace arg1 with the actual value of the argument you want to pass to the method. If your method requires multiple arguments, then you can pass like:
method, err := contractABI.Methods[methodName].Inputs.Pack(arg1, arg2, arg3, …)


The problem with your answer is that I don't know the abiJSON :=[...], the value has to be collected during runtime.
Even though every Token is a ERC20 token, I am using a new token every iteration.

Okay, is every token in your iteration has a verified corresponding token contract?

By the way, if all the tokens are standard ERC20, then you could use the common ERC20 token contract's ABI.

If the token contracts are verified, then you can fetch the ABIs using the Etherscan API.
